# Car insurance for UK to Iran trip

Tags: uk, driving, insurance, australian-citizens, iran

My husband and I are Australians who want to buy a car in the UK and drive it to Iran through Europe (incl. Eastern Europe), Turkey, Armenia, Azerbaijan etc. We want to leave ASAP once we have the practicalities sorted.

Our plan is to then drive back to the UK by Christmas and sell the car there (this way we don't have to pay for export etc).

It has been much more difficult than expected finding out about insurance for this, and I was hoping someone might be able to help us. Most importantly, we want to have third party liability insurance for the entire trip.

So, our questions are:

Has anyone else done this trip?

Did you buy international insurance? A few insurance companies (including Clements that I read about on a Horizons Unlimited thread) have said they will cover us for Europe and Turkey, but not Iran (or the 'Stans' area).

If you did manage to buy international insurance that covered Iran etc, who did you go through and how much did it cost (roughly)?

The other option we are considering is buying insurance for Europe and Turkey, then buying insurance at the border for these other countries (eg Iran). Does anyone know if this is possible, or have you done it? Is it easy enough to do?

Any other tips on sorting out the practicalities for such a trip, especially around insurance, would be very much appreciated.

P.S. We are buying the car in the UK instead of continental Europe because as Australians on a tourist visa we can't buy a car in Europe without residency. We know that they drive on the other side in the UK, so are looking for a left-hand vehicle there (and if that's not possible, we'll just have to cope!)

Comment: I can't answer your real questions, but about your plan to buy/sell a left-hand drive car in the UK: you can find them if you're looking for them, but there aren't many so you can't be too picky... I certainly wouldn't want to restrict my choice so much when planning a trip like yours. And selling it when you get back to the UK: nobody in the UK wants a left-hand drive car. Expect a long wait, unless you're willing to sell significantly below value.

Comment: What does "HOME Rent for 3 day" mean in the context of driving across Europe?

Comment: Looks like our friend copy pasted this https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/ShowTopic-g293998-i9139-k7657835-UK_to_Iran_and_back_insurance_question-Iran.html

Comment: ‘We can’t buy a car in Europe without a residency’. The UK is in Europe.

Comment: I am familiar with the insurance company called Clements, which caters to diplomats and others on overseas postings. I would be rather surprised if any insurance company would take on the risk associated with a once-off trip through several countries.

Comment: Turkey shares a 1,600 mile border with Iran and crossing it would be the most direct  route to Tehran and cities to the south. There is no need to transit Armenia or Azerbaijan; these two countries are also in a 'frozen conflict'.

Comment: There are no border crossings between Armenia & Azerbaijan. Like @RichardBeasley I'd avoid that area due to complications you may encounter in either country.